# Decrease in Instances Size Suddenly

Tags: cloud-foundry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6A2d.png)

I deployed a Spring boot Java Application in CF in one Org and Space , Initially i deployed the App with the 2 instances which is described in manifest file later due to the requirement i increased the number of instances to 4 but this i gave in cf push command "cf push appname -i 4 ", in script task bamboo, everything was running as expected but on friday suddenly the instances got decreased to 2 no changes in manifest or script , i checked the logs "cf logs app-name recent and cf events appname" there is no clue for app crash may i know what might be the reason for thi weird behaviour , do i need to check somewhere else, if app restarts suddenly would it take the manifest file ? please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you're referring to the total instance count or the currently running instance count.

### Running Instance Count

If you're currently running instance count does not match the total instance count, then there is some sort of problem with the instances. The app is crashing, you've scaled up/down recently and new instances couldn't be created, or perhaps your platform is undergoing maintenance and app instances are being shuffled around.

In all cases, you'd want to look at `cf events` and `cf logs` for clues. The event would tell you if it's an app crash or specific scaling event. If there's nothing in the event's output, it could be platform maintenance. That doesn't generate event entries.

### Total Instance Count

If the total instance count does not match what you'd expect, then it was changed by someone or something. The total count is stored in Cloud Controller and would not change unless it was directed.

If your total instance count is changing unexpectedly look at the `cf events` output. This will include entries that modify the application instance count, like `cf push` and `cf scale`. It should also tell you what made the change (the actor), so that can help to track down how it's being changed.

I'm not totally sure this is happening here, but I have seen others hit by this. If you do a one-off `cf push` or `cf scale`, that change will stick on the server. However, if you are using a `manifest.yml` file that contains state, i.e. your old instance count. If you or someone else or your CI then goes and does a `cf push` with the manifest.yml file that has the old instance count, that will update the instance count on Cloud Controller back to the old instance count.

In short, if you do a one-off `cf push` or `cf scale` to change the instance count, you need to make sure your `manifest.yml` is kept up-to-date & that is checked into CI (if you're doing that).

Lastly, check if you have any autoscaling rules in place. Those could also obviously impact your instance count. If you change your total instance count, you'll probably also want to update your scaling rules.

Comment: Attached a Screenshot in the above comment please find the one and share the feedback

Comment: Something using your `ci.cif` user is making the change. You can't say what exactly is happening from the event log, but the actor listed there is the user that's making the change. So you need to review where you are using that user & what it's doing. Something it's doing is causing the instance count to be changed. You could look at your cloud controller logs to possibly get some further detail. You should be able to find the individual request making the change & look up the IP that's sending the request.